# Apache Ranger-admin not showing active plugin

Tags: hadoop, authorization

I have setup Apache ranger authorization for Apache hadoop.

ranger-admin and ranger-usersync is running without any error.

I have also enabled ranger-hdfs-plugin and restarted hadoop, but active plugin list is empty in ranger-admin UI.

I don't see any error in any of the logs file. Can someone guide me how to resolve this issue ?

Ranger Version: 0.5

Comment: @santhosh, were you able to solve this issue? I know it's very long time ago but by any chance??